# Installing Android app on device from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to install my app on an Android phone (HTC One) but am not sure how to go about this.I ran the app but the device does not show in the `Choose Device` window that opens.What are the steps in doing this?

Comment: What OS are you using? There are special instructions depending on your OS on the android homepage. Did you read them? https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: ...and did you follow the instructions on the Android developer page (link above)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you activate "Developer options" on your device? You must allow USB debugging and also allow "Unknown sources" to install application outside of Play Store. Also you need to have correctly installed driver on your computer. Follow instructions from https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html .

Comment: It might also already be installed, just not on your devices "home" screen yet.  I had to search for mine in the installed apps.

Comment: thanks @technocrat - that was my issue. Found the app in the "apps" screen, dragged it to the home screen to make things easy.